# Search for a value in Array of Dictionaries of array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

Here is my response format :

```
[
  {
    "id": 9001,
    "name": "A to B",
    "description": "A to B via mooncity",
    "sequence":[
      1001,
      1002,
      1003
      ]
  },
 {
    "id": 9002,
    "name": "B to D",
    "description": "B to D via suncity",
    "sequence":[
      1010,
      1002,
      1009
      ]
  }
]
```

Now i want to get all dictionaries which has `1002` in their `sequence array` and put it into another array.

I tired

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[c] %@", @"sequence", @"1002"];
```

But the above predicate works well for array of dictionaries. Whereas it fails to work in this case.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `@"ANY sequence IN %@", @[@(1010)]]`. I put `@(number)`, because since it's JSON, it should be serialized into `NSNumber` (unless you format your self and turn the values into `NSString`.

Comment: My predicate is of the format `ANY stops_sequence IN {"1002"}`. It's not working though. Its returning empty array

Answer (score 2):

```
 NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"CAST(sequence, 'NSString') contains[cd] %@", @"1002"];
 NSArray *result = [your_array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

Answer (score 1):

in swift it will works for me

```
let array = ["101","110","133"]
    let dict = ["sequence":array,"id": "10"] as [String : AnyObject]

    let array1 = ["100","110","133"]
    let dict1 = ["sequence":array1,"id": "10"] as [String : AnyObject]

    let fArray : NSArray = [dict,dict1] as NSArray


    let pred = NSPredicate(format:  "ANY self.sequence contains[c] %@", "100")

    let test = fArray.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(pred)

    print(test)
```

out put

```
[{
id = 10;
sequence =     (
    100,
    110,
    133
);
```

}]

Comment: Thank you for your response @jignesh. Unfortunately, Its not working for me. App is crashing with the error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use in/contains operator with collection 1001 (not a collection)`

Comment: i have try above code in swift and it will work for me if "sequence" array contains string value if it contains int then it will crash application